# Div Not Responding to Width CSS

Tags: html, css, width

In the process of creating a form, and I want the text labels to all be the same width. For some reason that I cannot discern, using `width` is not working as in:

```
.form-label {  display:inline; width: 160px; }

<div class="form-label required">First Name:</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfXyH/)

How can I get the `.form-label` class to respond to the width declaration? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it from display:inline to display:inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

Object position as `inline` have no width attribute, i think you are looking for `inline-block;`

Comment: Just what I was about to say. @karl_Andre Ganon you are too fast :)

Comment: Thanks! Added +1 but have to give it to Becuzz.. becuz he/she answered first.